# Does the FS-R6B receiver work with the JJPRO EM-16 transmitter?

Tags: receiver, compatibility

If I need a new receiver and can't find one that is exactly the same as the one that came with the radio, can I get one with the same amount of channels and from the same company and use it with the radio?

Specifically, I need to know if [this receiver](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FXLZYMY) works with [this radio](https://www.banggood.com/JJRC-JJPRO-EM-16-2_4GHz-6CH-AFHDS-2A-Mode-2-RC-Transmitter-with-Receiver-Support-P175-for-RC-Drone-p-1724957.html?rmmds=search&cur_warehouse=CN).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various digital protocols, and many receivers are able to handle more than one protocol (and so can a few transmitters).

It looks like that transmitter uses "AFHDS 2A", so you need a receiver that can handle that.

That receiver (FS-R6B) says "AFHDS" on the label, and there's a big complicated chart (the 5th image) showing which receivers handle AFHDS 2A, but I can't see the FS-R6B on the chart so it's not much help. The binding instructions imply that it might do both.

Comment: So as long as the receiver is AFHDS 2A compatible, then it should work with the radio?

Comment: As long as both the TX and RX support the same protocol, yes they should work fine.